# Need solution to Non Egg Install of Mechanize - Py2exe fails

Tags: python, mechanize, py2exe

I have racked my brain on getting Mechanize to install without an egg in Win7.  I have tried the easy_install --allways-unzip method.  The easy_install -Z method.  Added .pth file in the site-packages directory.  Added combinations of the above.

Py2exe doesn't play nice with egg files.  If you have got this working, please reply.

Thanks - Brad

---

Some of the links I followed are:

[Mechanize not being installed by easy_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151256/mechanize-not-being-installed-by-easy-install)

[How to install mechanize for Python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888463/how-to-install-mechanize-for-python-2-7)

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/204941

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t691937-re-mechanize-not-recognized-by-py2exe.html

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't already read it there is a section on [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FrontPage) website about [dealing with eggs](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ExeWithEggs). I don't know how effective it is (I never install eggs), and [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FrontPage) can be tricky enough without dealing with an `egg` installed packages. I would do the one of the following:

1. Download the `mechanize` [source package](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/download.html), unzip it and edit its `setup.py` to change the `zip_safe` option to `False`. Then install mechanize from the command line:

   ```
   python setup.py install
   ```
2. use [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html) to do the install:

   ```
   pip install mechanize
   ```

   Of course you'd have to install [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html) first (`easy_install pip`). [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html) installs packages flat by default. (fyi - if you end up using `pip` on Windows you need to beware that it can't handle python packages that require compiling. Mechanize won't be a problem, but if it's something you start using with any regularity...)

Other than the `egg` issue there is nothing that I can see in mechanize's package structure that would indicate that py2exe would have any problems picking it up once it has been installed flat.

Comment: Both methods to install mechanize worked.  Py2exe builds without exceptions.  When I run the executable a log file is generated with the following ImportError: No Module Name Inspect.  When I run the program from the source I get no errors and it runs OK.  Any ideas, thanks for the post - Brad.

Answer (score 0):

The last install of mechanize used method 1 from @markgemmill as posted above.

I kept getting a log error: ImportError: No module named inspect when running my executable.

After adding inspect, calendar, etc... to the includes[] in py2exe setup.py, I realized that I should maybe I should change my code from:

```
    import mechanize
        to
    from mechanize import *
```

This worked.  The executable generated from py2exe runs!

A noob mistake.  Always learning...  Brad